# Continuous Integration build over TFS2017

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, build-definition, vnext

I would like to know what is the equivalent of "Continuous Integration - build each check-in" (XAML definition) in VNext definitions.

1- Is it "Run continuous integration triggers for commited changes" in Gated trigger?

2-Or it is a "Continuous Integration trigger with batch changes checked" in build definition.

I ask this question because I was not able to launch a CI build after successfully Gated Check-in. My CI build does different steps than Gated.

I'm over TFS 2017 (15.117.27414.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of "Continuous Integration - build each check-in" (XAML definition) in VNext definitions is **Continuous Integration** trigger:

[image]

> Enable CI trigger if you want the build to run whenever someone checks
>   in code.
>
> Select **Batch changes** check box if you have a lot of team members
>   uploading changes often and you want to reduce the number of builds
>   you are running. If you select this option, when a build is running,
>   the system waits until the build is completed and then queues another
>   build of all changes that have not yet been built.
>
> Select the version control paths you want to include and exclude. In
>   most cases, you should make sure that these filters are consistent
>   with your TFVC mappings on the `Repository` tab.

You can get more details in the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers?view=vsts

Comment: Thanks Cece for the response. I tried this option but the CI is not launched after success Gated check-in.

The CI include path is the same as Gated build definition. Could it be a TFS 2017 issue?

Comment: What's the meaning of "CI is not launched after success Gated check-in"? Do you want to use CI or Gated Check-in? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Yes, two build definitions (Gated & CI).


User commits some changes.


**Gated:**
The solution is compiled in debug mode.
Tests are executed.


Once Gated commit the changes, CI is launched (automatically).


**CI:**
The solution is compiled in release mode.
Tests are executed.
Increase the assembly version.


I cannot execute this process in VNext builds. CI is not launched after gated check-in. I've been using this kind of process with XAML definitions.

Comment: Do you mean you have two build definitions mapping the same repo? One build definition is using Gate Check-in trigger, another one is using CI trigger, but CI is not triggered when you submit changes?

Comment: Yes, this is the case. Do you think that it would have to work?

Comment: If you want to run CI build after Gated build, you need to checked `Run continuous integration triggers for committed changes` in the Gated build definition.

Comment: I've selected that option and it seems to work properly. This option didn't work as expected in TFS2015.

So thanks for the support.